# SVG not scaling properly in IE

Tags: svg, scaling

I am using this [plugin](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/) on this [website](http://thegarrettco.com/). The plugin generates an SVG map of the US. I am scaling the map to 100% of the parent container width and height like so:

```
svg {

    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

}
```

This works perfectly on all browsers except for IE versions <= 11. I've been looking all over for solutions but have yet to find anything that works for me. Most of the solutions point to setting the viewbox attribute, which is indeed set, but that is being set by the plugin. Is it just not being set properly on IE? I'm kind of at a loss as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. My 'preserveAspectRatio' property had the value 'xMinYMin meet', when I changed it to 'xMinYMin slice' it scaled properly in IE.